# Unable to configure SonarLint plugin on Idea IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I'm trying to configure the SonarLint plugin (Version - 3.2.0.2350) on Idea Intellij (Ultimate Edition. Version: 2017.3.4, Build: 173.4548.28) but I get an error when trying to `Update binding` - `**Analyzers not loaded**. The following plugins do not meet the required minimum versions, please upgrade them. typescript (installed1.1.0, minimum 1.5)`.

Although I am still able to go ahead and Update the Project list, find my project and save the settings, whenever I try to Analyze any file, it says `Cannot create ClassLoader`. 
I do not have any separate Typescript plugin installed apart from the `Javascript Support` plugin. And the updated to the latest version 1.0.

Can anyone help with this ?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the [SonarTS](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS/releases) plugin is not installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest release of the SonarLint common library (used by most SonarLint flavors) [unlock support of SonarTS](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLCORE-168). This is not yet officially supported in SonarLint for IntelliJ, but it will come.

SonarLint requires at least SonarTS 1.5, and it seems your have SonarTS 1.1.0 installed on your SonarQube server. So basically SonarLint is asking you to update it, and will ignore the plugin.

The classloader error should come from something else, but we need a stacktrace to better understand (look at SonarLint logs).

Comment: Thanks Julien for pointing out that I need to look for the plugin on SonarQube server. I was looking for it on my local setup.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with: Idea 2018.1.3 and sonar lint plugin 3.4.0.2532. I was told that our SonarTS is 1.6 (build 2388).

Comment: Same problem with IntelliJ 2018.1.4, SonarLint plugin 3.4.2.2586, SonarQube 6.7.1.  The erro message on the IDE is deceiving: how can one know it's about a plugin on the server?! Just say "The follogin plugins *on the sonarqube server* do not meet..."